# saslauthd authentication error

Tags: email, postfix, ubuntu-10.04, sasl, saslauthd

My server has developed an expected problem where I am unable to connect from a mail client.

I've looked at the server logs and the only thing that looks to identify a problem are events like the following:

> Nov 23 18:32:43 hig3 dovecot: imap-login: Login:
>   user=, method=PLAIN, rip=xxxxxxxx,
>   lip=xxxxxxx, TLS Nov 23 18:32:55 hig3 postfix/smtpd[11653]:
>   connect from xxxxxxx.co.uk[xxxxxxx] Nov 23
>   18:32:55 hig3 postfix/smtpd[11653]: warning: SASL authentication
>   failure: cannot connect to saslauthd server: No such file or directory
>   Nov 23 18:32:55 hig3 postfix/smtpd[11653]: warning:
>   xxxxxxx.co.uk[xxxxxxxx]: SASL LOGIN
>   authentication failed: generic failure Nov 23 18:32:56 hig3
>   postfix/smtpd[11653]: lost connection after AUTH from
>   xxxxxxx.co.uk[xxxxxxx] Nov 23 18:32:56 hig3
>   postfix/smtpd[11653]: disconnect from
>   xxxxxxx.co.uk[xxxxxxx]

The problem is unusual, because just half an hour previously at my office, I was not being prompted for a correct username and password in my mail client. I haven't made any changes to the server, so I can't understand what would have happened to make this error occur.

Searches for the error messages yield various results, with 'fixes' that I'm uncertain of (obviously don't want to make it worse or fix something that isn't broken).

When I run

> testsaslauthd -u xxxxx -p xxxxxx

I also get the following result:

> connect() : No such file or directory

But when I run

> testsaslauthd -u xxxxx -p xxxxxx -f
>   /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/mux -s smtp

I get:

> 0: OK "Success."

I found those commands on another forum and am not entirely sure what they mean, but I'm hoping they might give an indication of where the problem might lie.

When I run

> ps -ef|grep saslauthd

This is the output:

> root      1245     1  0 Nov24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a
>   pam -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r -n 5 root      1250 
>   1245  0 Nov24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m
>   /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r -n 5 root      1252  1245  0
>   Nov24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m
>   /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r -n 5 root      1254  1245  0
>   Nov24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m
>   /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r -n 5 root      1255  1245  0
>   Nov24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m
>   /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r -n 5 root      5902  5885  0
>   08:51 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto saslauthd

If it makes any difference, I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.1, Postfix 2.7.0 and Webmin/ Virtualmin.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Postfix can run in a chroot (by default in `/var/spool/postfix`) or not. If it is, it will try to open `/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/mux` for sasl authentication. If it's not, it will try to open `/var/run/saslauthd/mux`

It seems that, for some reason, your postfix instance was running in a chroot, and it's not anymore. It's odd, but that's what I guess from the details of your question. If it's what's happened, you may change saslauthd configuration to use `/var/run/saslauthd` or run postfix in a chroot again.

To know if your Postfix is running chroot, you can check `/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

1. If it has the line `smtp inet n - y - - smtpd` or `smtp inet n - - - - smtpd`, then your **Postfix is running in a chroot**;
2. If it has the line `smtp inet n - n - - smtpd` then your **Postfix is NOT running in a chroot**.

This check comes from `/etc/default/saslauthd` (Ubuntu sasl configuration file).

Comment: Your answer has just crystalised the link between the line in master.cf and chroot - thank you! Although I'm sure I'd checked this countless times earlier, for whatever reason, I missed the third 'n'. I'm mystified as to how it came to suddenly change in the master.cf file, though.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like `postfix` always looks in the chroot'ed location for `saslauthd` even though its configured to **NOT** use the chroot environment for its services.

I found this blog post most helpful, even though it's from 2005!

http://www.jimmy.co.at/weblog/?p=52

> postfix does a chroot so it can’t communicate with saslauthd. This is
>   the tricky part:
>
> ```
> rm -r /var/run/saslauthd/ 
> mkdir -p /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd 
> ln -s /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd /var/run 
> chgrp sasl /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd 
> adduser postfix sasl
> ```

You can run `saslauthd` in debug mode using:

`saslauthd -c -d -a pam -m /var/run/saslauthd`

From your client, do this:

`openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -starttls smtp -connect mail.mydomain.com:587`

When prompted type this:

```
HELO mynotebook.com
LOGIN PLAIN <base64code>
```

where the `base64code` bit comes from this:

```
perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("\000username\000password");'
```

Answer (score 2):

No such file or directory when trying to connect suggests the UNIX socket it is looking for SASLAuthd on doesn't exist.

If you run `ps -ef | grep saslauthd`, can you see it still running?

If so, maybe see if it has its own log location.

If not it could just need a restart.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think it's running - I've added the output to my question and am assuming that the output shows that it's running. I've restarted both the server and the service, but to no avail. Why might this have happened without any intervention on my part? Seems like an odd thing to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Every time I've encountered a similar problem with saslauthd (and when everything else has been double-checked), it has been about directory/file permissions. Check each and every step of this `/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd` path to make sure saslauthd actually can get there.